# Data account ownership

Tags: solana-program, web3.js

As I understand from the link https://solanacookbook.com/core-concepts/accounts.html#account-model that Data account is owned by a Program, and that Program can only modify the data.

Let's say, I deploy a counter program with id 'xyz...klm', then I create a data account using createAccountWithSeed function signed by account 'abc..lmn' and modify the counter. Now, if I call the same program by the passing the same data account and signing the transaction with a different account 'def..abc', the counter is still changed. I would like that the data account can only be modified by 'abc..lmn'and not any other account. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is something a smart contract has to implement itself. If you only want a single pubkey to be the `authority` of some account and whether its data gets updated, then you need to add a check to your program that the `authority` has signed the transaction. In anchor that can be done with the `Signer<'info>` type inside the derive accounts macro.

Comment: Ok, I am not using Anchor :(

What I have currently done is - passed the data account and the required account in the accounts list while sending the transaction (in the client). In the program, I checked if the signer's key matches the expected key, if yes then move on. 

Now, what I would like is to fetch the expected key from a PDA, I guess or somewhere externally. Any thoughts?